# Stopping bash running in a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I am writing a python script that calls a bash script.

```
from subprocess import call
rc = call("./try_me.sh")
```

How can I exit the running bash file without exiting the running python script?
I need something like Ctrl + C.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen()` instead, and send the subprocess a `SIGINT` signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Some research, I found I should have used Popen to run the bash file as @AKX suggested.

```
from subprocess import Popen
r1 = Popen('printf "*Systempassword* \n" |sudo -S  ./try_me.sh &', shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid))
```

when you need to stop running the bash file

```
import os
os.killpg(os.getpgid(r1.pid), signal.SIGTERM) # Send the signal to all the process groups
```

Answer (score 0):

There's different ways to approach this problem.

It appears that you're writing some sort of CLI tool since you referenced Ctrl+C.  If that's the case you can use `&` and send a SIGINT signal to stop it when you need.

```
import os
os.system('nohup ./try_me.sh &')
```

If you want stricter control try using async subprocess management:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html